# How to unzip a file using 7zip app.. i am using below code but its doesnt extract the file, is there any mistake in shell str?

Tags: vba

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
Public Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = &H400
Public Const STILL_ACTIVE = &H103

Public Sub ShellAndWait(ByVal PathName As String, Optional WindowState)
    Dim hProg As Long
    Dim hProcess As Long, ExitCode As Long
    'fill in the missing parameter and execute the program
    If IsMissing(WindowState) Then WindowState = 1
    hProg = Shell(PathName, WindowState)
    'hProg is a "process ID under Win32. To get the process handle:
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, hProg)
    Do
        'populate Exitcode variable
        GetExitCodeProcess hProcess, ExitCode
        DoEvents
    Loop While ExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE
End Sub

Sub B_UnZip_Zip_File_Fixed()

    Dim PathZipProgram As String, NameUnZipFolder As String
    Dim FileNameZip As Variant, ShellStr As String

    'Path of the Zip program
    PathZipProgram = "c:\program files\7-Zip"
    If Right(PathZipProgram, 1) <> "\" Then
        PathZipProgram = PathZipProgram & "\"
    End If

    'Check if this is the path where 7z is installed.
    If dir(PathZipProgram & "7z.exe") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please find your copy of 7z.exe and try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'You can also use a fixed path like
    NameUnZipFolder = "C:\Users\Bala\Documents\Test"

    'Name of the zip file that you want to unzip (.zip or .7z files)
    FileNameZip = "C:\Users\Bala\Documents\Test\bala.vignesh.zip"
    If dir(NameUnZipFolder & "bala.vignesh.zip") = "" Then
        MsgBox "bala.zip file not available please check"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ShellStr = PathZipProgram & "7z.exe e -aou -r" _
             & " " & Chr(34) & FileNameZip & Chr(34) _
             & " -o" & Chr(34) & NameUnZipFolder & Chr(34) & " " & "*.*"

    ShellAndWait ShellStr, vbHide
    MsgBox "Look in " & NameUnZipFolder & " for extracted files"

End Sub
```